# How to make a dynamic area in CSS Grid without affecting other areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So here is the problem. I want a layout that looks like this, where `C` grows dynamically with more content. 
[image: what I want]

However, this is what I am getting. Basically, the row of `A` is growing together with `C`: 
[image: what I am getting]

My wrapper code with template-area:

```
wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.64fr 1fr 5fr 0.64fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    ". A C ."
    ". B C .";
}
```

I've thought about just grouping `A` and `B` into a single column, then use flexbox. However, is there a more CSS Grid way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use flexbox for your *sidebar* and using:

```
grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    ". sidebar C ."
```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.64fr 1fr 5fr 0.64fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    ". sidebar C .";
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.A {
  background: pink;
  
}
.B {
  background: orange;
}

.C {
  grid-area: C;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="C">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Another approach would be to have one more row in your CSS grid - note the usage of an  *psuedo element* to fill the space below `A` and `B`.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.64fr 1fr 5fr 0.64fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header"
    ". A C ."
    ". B C ."
    ". D C .";
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  grid-area: D;
  background: lightblue;
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: lightblue;
}

.A {
  grid-area: A;
  background: pink;
  
}
.B {
  grid-area: B;
  background: orange;
}

.C {
  grid-area: C;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The second answer is the good one!   But you don't really need the pseudo element at all. It will still work without it . And in the areas specification, change D for a dot.

Comment: yeah, *dot* works too, I was thinking of filling it with the *background* as in the question :)